# The page is currently unavailable

Tags: php, nginx

I wanna set up nginx server to work with PHP and MySQL. To do so, I have:

1. Downloaded nginx files, unzipped it (`C:/nginx/`)
2. Downloaded PHP binaries and put them inside `C:/nginx/php/`
3. Changed C:/nginx/conf/nginx.conf to

---

```
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

And unfortunately, I can't get .php files to working. Trying to run one only displays "Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable." message.

I have clean environment, so all I have is nginx and php...What's wrong here?

Comment: You need to install php-fpm for running php in nginx. You also need t change this line

Answer (score 0):

You need to install php-fpm for running php in nginx. You also need t change this line

```
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
```

to this one

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

Change to this unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; to php-fpm sock file path.

Comment: I didn't mention I'm running it on windows, but thanks, I'll give it a try.